N asterisks in a row then N-1 asterisks in a row and so forth, in C language
As a beginner in c,
I am trying to do N asterisks in a row (and N lines) in C.
Example with n = 3:
Expected Result:
***
**
*

I tried with this code
int main(void)
    int n;
    while (1) {
        printf("Please input a positive number\n");
        scanf(" %d", &n);
        if (n > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; n >= i; i++) {
        printf("*");
    }

I only managed to do N asterisk on one row, how can i update my code to match the expected output

A good easy approach is to have 2 loops: an outer loop for managing lines; and an inner loop to manage asterisks in the current line.

This isn't a [mcve].  And where are you stuck?  There's not even an attempt for multiple rows here.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

"I only managed to do N asterisk on one row" - What happens when you try to add the remaining rows?  If you know that the loop from 1 to n makes the first row, what would make the next row?  If you write out each row as its own loop, do those loops look like they're repeating?  Are they repeating in a pattern?  Can you express that pattern in a loop?

scanf("%d", ... means "ignore optional whitespace and read an integer"; scanf(" %d", ... means "ignore optional whitespace and ignore optional whitespace and read an integer" :-)

As @pmg said, adding a second loop to print each line can be a great option
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    while (1) {
        printf("Please input a positive number\n");
        scanf(" %d", &n);
        if (n > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Write N line
    for (int line = 0; line < n; line ++) {
        // In each lines write n - line asterisk
        for (int column = 0; column < n - line; column ++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        // At the end of the line print the newline character
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

The n - line is the part that allow you to do your pattern of N-1 on each line.
I reccommend you starting your for loops with index 0 if it's possible.
I also recommend you to search for neested loops in C, here are 2 examples for you:

Basic Logic
More examples


Such kinds of problems are solved with nested for loops. Here is an example code that might help
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int rows; // Number of rows in the pattern

    printf("Please input a positive number\n");
    scanf(" %d", &rows);
    
    for (int i = rows; i > 0; i--) { 
        // Loop through each row, starting from rows variable to 1
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n"); // Move to the next line after printing stars in each row
    }
    return 0;
}


If you want to use only one loop you can use string and memset
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void print(unsigned rows)
{
    char line[rows + 1];
    memset(line, '*', rows);
    line[rows] = 0;

    for(unsigned row = rows; row; row--)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        line[row - 1] = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    print(5);
    printf("----------\n");
    print(0);
    printf("----------\n");
    print(1);
    printf("----------\n");
    print(2);
    printf("----------\n");
    print(3);
    printf("----------\n");
}

https://godbolt.org/z/nnYcsY9ds

Or maybe printf("%.*s\n", (int)row, line); and delete the line shrinking statement.

@pmg taking into account OPs level I was trying to avoid fancy printf formats to keep it simple
